# Meal plan algorithm closest to x calories with types

Tags: python, algorithm, mathematical-optimization, combinatorics

I have a problem where I need to generate a **meal plan** with:

- x number of meals per day (eg. 5)
- x number of meal types in the plan (eg. 2 breakfasts, 2 snacks and 1 lunch)
- Number of calories in meal plan (eg. 2000)
- There should be no duplicate meals

The given data is a list of dictionaries (over 100,000 units) structured this way:

```
{'title': 'Cannellini Bean and Asparagus Salad with Mushrooms', 'types': ['side dish', 'lunch', 'main course', 'salad', 'main dish', 'dinner'], 'calories': 482}
```

The output of the algorithm should be a list of x meals closest to the x calories, with their associated meal types.

I have no idea where to start with this problem, any algorithm type or implementation is welcome.

Comment: Do you count it as a different meal plan if the exact same dishes show up assigned to different meal types?  For example if we had a Caesar and bean salad both assignable to lunch and salad, does which one is assigned where matter?

Comment: @btilly no it doesn’t count, forgot to include it

Comment: This seems like a variant where you optimize subset-sum under constraints, so I suspect it's NP-hard. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) may have inspiration.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/ / https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: @Neil It's not really the subset-sum problem because here, the size of the subset is fixed. But I agree it feels like NP-hard.

Comment: I suspect you’d do better over on or.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem is NP-hard. That does not mean we cannot solve it, however: we can often use techniques from constraint programming to solve such problems quickly.

Some parameters for your constraints:

```py
NUM_MEALS = 5
MEAL_TYPES = ['breakfast', 'dinner', 'lunch', 'snack']
REQUIRED_MEALS = [1, 1, 1, 2]
TARGET_CALORIES = 2_000
TOLERANCE = 50
```

I assume there are four meal types, each having a particular amount of times they need to be present in a meal plan (here, each of breakfast, dinner, and lunch are required to be present once, and we need two snacks). We also have a caloric requirement of 2K total calories, and a tolerance on what we consider OK: anything in the range `[2K - 50, 2K + 50]` will do. We need a bit of a tolerance since it's not always possible to find a perfect set of meals that reaches 2K calories exactly. Feel free to change the tolerance to whatever you think is reasonable.

To generate some random data of appropriate size:

```py
def make_random_meal_options():
    options = []

    for _ in range(100_000):
        calories = np.random.randint(100, 1_000)
        num_types = np.random.randint(1, len(MEAL_TYPES))
        types = np.random.choice(MEAL_TYPES, num_types, replace=False)

        options.append(dict(calories=calories, types=types))

    # List of dictionaries with keys 'calories' and 'types'
    return options

meal_options = make_random_meal_options()
```

We generate 100K dictionaries representing meals: each dictionary has a number of calories (uniform in `[100, 1000]`) and a set of meal types it can fulfil.

It is helpful if we have the calories as a numpy array, along with a boolean matrix matching meals and meal types:

```py
import numpy as np

calories = np.array([option['calories'] for option in meal_options])

# Element (i, j) == True iff meal i has meal type j, and False otherwise.
meal_types = np.empty((len(meal_options), len(MEAL_TYPES)), dtype=bool)

for i, option in enumerate(meal_options):
    for j, meal_type in enumerate(MEAL_TYPES):
        meal_types[i, j] = meal_type in option['types']
```

To specify the model I will use Google OR-Tools' [CP solver](https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/cp_example), since that's freely available software.

```py
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

model = cp_model.CpModel()

# Decision variables, one for each meal and meal type: meal[i, j] is 1 iff
# meal i is assigned to meal type j, and 0 otherwise.
meal_vars = np.empty((len(meal_options), len(MEAL_TYPES)), dtype=object)

for i in range(len(meal_options)):
    for j in range(len(MEAL_TYPES)):
        meal_vars[i, j] = model.NewBoolVar(f"meal[{i}, {j}]")

# We want the overall caloric value of the meal plan to be within bounds.
lb, ub = [TARGET_CALORIES - TOLERANCE, TARGET_CALORIES + TOLERANCE]
model.AddLinearConstraint(calories @ meal_vars.sum(axis=1), lb, ub)

for j, meal_type in enumerate(MEAL_TYPES):
    # Need the required amount of meals of each type.
    model.Add(meal_types[:, j] @ meal_vars[:, j] == REQUIRED_MEALS[j])

for i in range(len(meal_options)):
    # Each meal can only be selected once across all meal types.
    model.Add(meal_vars[i, :].sum() <= 1)

# Need NUM_MEALS meals in the meal plan
model.Add(meal_vars.sum() == NUM_MEALS)

solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
status = solver.Solve(model)

if status == cp_model.OPTIMAL or status == cp_model.FEASIBLE:
    print(f"Solving took {solver.WallTime():.2f} seconds")

    for i in range(len(meal_options)):
        for j in range(len(MEAL_TYPES)):
            if solver.Value(meal_vars[i, j]) > 0:
                option = meal_options[i]
                cal = option['calories']
                mt = MEAL_TYPES[j]

                print(f"Selected meal {i} with {cal} calories for {mt}.")
else:
    print("No solution found.")
```

This is a constraint programming model that has a boolean selection variable (yes/no) for the assignment of meals to meal types, and several constraints on these variables: each meal can only be selected once across all meal types, the selected meals need to sum to a caloric value within the tolerance bounds, there need to be sufficient meals of each type, and we need exactly `NUM_MEALS` meals.

When I run this on my machine after fixing the seed to `42`, I get:

```
Solving took 19.07 seconds
Selected meal 1682 with 100 calories for lunch.
Selected meal 76138 with 999 calories for snack.
Selected meal 86843 with 100 calories for breakfast.
Selected meal 95861 with 100 calories for snack.
Selected meal 99987 with 706 calories for dinner.
```

The runtime is well under a minute, and the meal plan works. This problem is solvable despite being NP-hard.

Comment: There is something I don't understand. In your model, where do you choose the type of a meal? If a meal is both a lunch and a dinner, you should decide if you consider it a lunch or a dinner (it can't be both). You print `option['types']`, which is the full list of types. In your sample solution, the lists have only one element, but it's just an accident, isn't it?

Comment: @Olivier that's something one can easily do in a postprocessing step. It's a variant of an assignment problem, so not hard to solve using for example a max flow algorithm. It's also possible to add the explicit assignments to the model, at the cost of significantly more variables. That's likely much slower to solve. "your model forces the selection of meals that have only type." is, however, false.

Comment: Did you try replacing `np.random.randint(1, ...)` with `np.random.randint(2, ...)` to see if it still works?

Comment: @Olivier yes, works fine. I've updated this to do the explicit assignments of meals to meal types. That's about 3x slower than an implicit meal plan, but in this case 20s vs 7s seems acceptable.

Comment: This is awesome, thank you, however i dont undetstand where the varable model comes from and what it resembles.

Comment: @AndreyKiselev my apologies, I mistakenly forgot to copy that over to this SO answer. I've just added it in! It's a [`CpModel`](https://developers.google.com/optimization/reference/python/sat/python/cp_model#cp_model.CpModel) instance.